# How can I skip the label if the value label already exists on my state but the new value will be included?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, use-state

I have a dropdown select field where I can choose different attributes value. The problem is when I try to store the selected data in the state I got twice the label which I don't need. I want if the label already exists in my state the labels will not include but the selected value will include.

My selected objects:

[image]

Expected Output:

```
{label: "colors"
    selected: Array(2)
         0: {label: 'Black', value: 1}
         1: {label: 'Green', value: 2}
      }, 
{label: "size"
       selected: Array(1)
         0: {label: 'M', value: 1}
} ]
```

I am trying like this but am confused about how can I skip the label if the value label already exists.

```
    const previousValue = (label: string, e: any) => {
        let isExist: any;
        if (newAttributes?.length > 0) {
            isExist = newAttributes.find((attr: any) => attr.label === label)
        }
        console.log(isExist);

        const newValue = { label: label, selected: e }
        setNewAttributes((oldArray: any): any => {
            if (isExist) {
                // confused how can I skip the label

            } else {
                return [...oldArray, newValue]
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. What's the need to merge the old value with the new one? Do you wish to merge the object(array item) if an object with the same label already exists? Is your select of type `multiple`?

Comment: @Shreshth I want my label to not show up again once inside the object, just add the new value inside my selected array, and my dropdown field is multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the method `findIndex` instead of `find` to find if the item exists in `newAttributes` array.

`findIndex` returns `-1` when item doesnt exist in the array and returns the index of the item otherwise. You could use that index to get the Object and update it.

```
    const previousValue = (label: string, e: any) => {
      let itemIndex: any;
      if (newAttributes ? .length > 0) {
        itemIndex = newAttributes.findIndex((attr: any) => attr.label === label)
      }

      const newValue = {
        label: label,
        selected: e
      }
      setNewAttributes((oldArray: any): any => {
        if (itemIndex >= 0) {
          // item exists at newAttributes[itemIndex]

          let updatedArr = [...oldArray];
          updatedArr[itemIndex] = {
            ...updatedArr[itemIndex],
            selected: [...updatedArr[itemIndex].selected, e]
          }
          return updatedArr;
        } else {
          return [...oldArray, newValue]
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but I am getting error `TypeError: updatedArr[itemIndex] is not iterable`

Comment: sorry, it should be ````selected: [...updatedArr[itemIndex].selected, e]````

Comment: I just removed updateArr from selected:[] now it's working. Thanks for your solution